# Javadoc: How to link to a module

Tags: javadoc, java-module

According to [the javadoc docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/javadoc/doc-comment-spec.html#see), one can use `@see` and `@link` to link to a module. It even says:

> A trailing / can be added to a name to refer to a module in the presence of a package or class with the same name.

However, when I use `@see some.module/`, I always end up with a broken link. Here is a minimal example:

```java
/**
 * @see java.base/
 */
module com.example.module {

}
```

which results in this:

[image: invalid @see]

Comment: Are you really running javadoc or just looking at a rendered output inside your IDE?

Comment: The second screenshot is from the html file produced by the maven-javafoc-plugin. IDE shows the same problems though, but I guess it simply doesn’t know about this spec yet. Just try it yourself

Comment: Well, I tried command line javadoc and had no such issue. That’s why I asked. So the next thing to verify would be which javadoc executable maven runs behind the scenes.

Comment: Turns out it works after all. I can't tell what caused this, as I don't even have any JDK < 11 installed. Maybe it depends on the state of the Maven reactor in multi-module builds. I can no longer reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It can be a simple case of accessibility.

If you see as I tried I was not able to view few modules.

[image]

So I suspect that `java.base` and `java.compiler` are not open and not accessible by default.

You can try for other modules, it should work.

Comment: Use a custom module, java.base was just an example. If you take a closer look at your example, you will notice, that you link to *packages*, not to *modules*. Use the trailing `/` to be explicit.

Comment: You surely do not need a module to be open to link against it. And `java.base` should always be accessible. All you have demonstrated, is that this editor doesn’t understand javadoc links to modules. `java.security` is a package inside `java.base` and `jdk.jshell` happens to be also a package inside the module `jdk.jshell`.